# Can't install PCL with Homebrew on OSX 10.9 during ROS Hydro installation

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro, mavericks, homebrew, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone! I've been following this tutorial (**wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source**) and got some great help from you all before. I need a little more help before I can get onto my feet and hopefully start helping others.

I am **trying to install ROS Hydro on OSX 10.9 through Homebrew**. Following the above linked tutorial, I am stuck trying to run this:

> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y

And it will fail trying to install PCL. So I try running "brew install pcl" instead. I get:

> Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>
> make: * * * [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

...along with a referral to the homebrew troubleshooting page.

Hansg91 suggested trying "brew install pcl -v" for more verbose output. Here's what I saw that I thought might be relevant:

> ==> make

> CMake Error: Parse error in cache file /tmp/vtk5-1lKn/VTK5.10.1/build/CMakeCache.txt. Offending entry: File "setup_install_paths.py", line xxx, in module.

This error was repeated several times with different lines being mentioned and different error reasons mentioned (in module, in get_install_path, TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getitem' - and more).

The final error listed that seemed to sum it all up was that **vtk5 5.10.1 did not build** - how might I be able to fix this?

I'm dead stuck. I have been following the tutorial to the letter, because otherwise I'd have no idea what I'm doing. Any ideas on how to get past this and continue with the installation? I can always provide more details if necessary. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173654/can%27t-install-pcl-with-homebrew-on-osx-10.9-during-ros-hydro-installation/) by [jc17](https://answers.ros.org/users/18797/jc17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2014-06-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-06-17**:
This is perhaps stating the obvious, but do you have vtk5 installed? What does "brew info vtk5" say?

**Comment by [jc17](https://answers.ros.org/users/18797/jc17/) on 2014-06-19**:
It was installed at the time, but following demmeln's suggestion fixed things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, it would be good to provide the full verbose output (use a service like pastebin.com and post the link).

With your hint towards vtk5, I just noticed that there were some recent changes with the vtk5 formula, but I'm not sure if that is indeed the problem you are seeing. I would try the following:

```
brew update
brew tap --repair
brew uninstall vtk5
brew uninstall pcl
brew install pcl --HEAD
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jc17](https://answers.ros.org/users/18797/jc17/) on 2014-06-19**:
This sequence ended up being the answer. D'oh, I'm a newbie to a lot of things in this universe and had no idea how often things update. Thank you!

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-06-19**:
Yes there are many moving targets for installing ROS... glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try "brew install pcl --HEAD" which I believe copies the latest version from git and tries to compile that. You could also try doing "brew install pcl -v" for a more verbose output, so that it is more clear what is going on.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2014-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jc17](https://answers.ros.org/users/18797/jc17/) on 2014-06-16**:
Thanks for the suggestions! Adding "--HEAD" on the end gave an identical result. Trying to add "-v" provided a few more clues. I edited my original question to show what errors were given.